# How to print the element in a list with index?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the element with the index of every element in the list

But my implement prints every element with index 0 and every element with index 1 until the last index

can anyone fix it, I'm stuck here?

```
if __name__=="__main__":

    r = [6, 5, 3, 3]
    diff = [[(i,j)for i in r]for j in range(5)]
    print(diff)
```

Actual output:

```
[[(6, 0), (5, 0), (3, 0), (3, 0)], [(6, 1), (5, 1), (3, 1), (3, 1)], [(6, 2), (5, 2), (3, 2), (3, 2)], [(6, 3), (5, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3)], [(6, 4), (5, 4), (3, 4), (3, 4)]]
```

Desired output:

`[(6, 0),(5, 1),(3, 2),(3, 3)]`

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: [(6, 0),(5, 1),(3, 2),(3, 3)]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/522563/139010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
diff = [(i, j) for j, i in enumerate(r)]
```

A less preferrable way would be to use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
diff = list(zip(r, range(len(r))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) , which gives you the element with index like this:

```
>>> r = [6, 5, 3, 3]
>>> output = [(val, indx) for indx, val in enumerate(r)]
>>> output
[(6, 0), (5, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

a simple way to understand enumerate:

```
diff = [(r[i], i) for i in range(len(r))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for the functionality provided by `enumerate()` (getting both the value and index of an iterable)

```
r = [6, 5, 3, 3]
print([(val, i) for i, val in enumerate(r)])
```